# Script to Move Directory by Combined Size

Tags: bash, directory

In a main directory, eg `/media/date/` There are a bunch of sub folders like so:

`/media/date/resource1/a-lot-of.files`

`/media/date/resource2/a-lot-of.files`

`/media/date/resource3/a-lot-of.files`

I want to have a script or a command that scans the sizes of each `resource` level folder, then moves them together under `/media/date/1-fold/resouceX, resourceY` Until it goes up to ~1TB. Then it will move the next batch to a new folder like `2-fold`

I have in mind `df` and `mv` but don't know how to go on from there. Any input is welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
src_path="/media/date/resource"
dest_path="/media/date/dir"
dir_suffix="0"
curr_total="0"
ONE_TERRA=$(( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 )) # in KB

for folder in "${src_path}"*; do
    if ! [[ -d "${folder}" ]]; then continue; fi
    if ! [[ -d "${dest_path}${dir_suffix}" ]]; then
        mkdir "${dest_path}${dir_suffix}"
    folder_size=$(du -s "${folder}" | grep -E -o "[[:digit:]]+")
    curr_total=$(( curr_total + folder_size ))
    mv "${folder}" "${dest_path}${dir_suffix}"
    if (( curr_total > ONE_TERRA )); then
        dir_suffix=$(( dir_suffix + 1 ))
    fi
```

Steps are as follows:

1. for each node of the pattern `/media/date/resource*`
2. if it isn't a directory, continue
3. if the dest dir doesn't exist, create it
4. get the size of the dir to move in KB
5. add it to the curr total of dest dir
6. move the dir to dest dir
7. if the curr dest dir size is over one terra, increment the dest dir suffix.

I have not tested the code.